# Give name to a constraint

Tags: constraints, informix

Is it possible to name the constraints in a table?
The problem I am facing is that when a constraints does not succeed I get a cryptic message instead of a clear name of which constraint it failed.

I tried something like :

```
primer_nombre   varchar(25) NOT NULL CHECK 'is_it_valid?' (primer_nombre MATCHES '^[a-zA-Z]$' )
```

But this fails. So Im stuck here.

```
CREATE TABLE Usuarios
 (
  CI  INT PRIMARY KEY,
  primer_nombre   varchar(25) NOT NULL CHECK (primer_nombre MATCHES '^[a-zA-Z]$' ),
  segundo_nombre   varchar(25),
  primer_apellido   varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  segundo_apellido   varchar(25),
  grado INT CHECK ( grado > 0 AND grado < 8),
  fecha_nacimiento DATE NOT NULL,
  nota INT CHECK ( nota > 0 AND nota < 13),
  email varchar(80),
  hace_proyecto boolean,
  tipo varchar(20) CHECK (tipo IN ('Admin', 'Docente', 'Alumno')),
  encriptacion_hash varchar(250),
  encriptacion_sal varchar(250),
  baja boolean 
 );
```

#### Output I get :

```
 530: Check constraint (admin_proyecto.c106_43) failed.
Error in line 7
Near character position 127
```

I would like to get a clearer message than that.

Comment: Pretty sure you are getting that error in a INSERT, not a CREATE TABLE and because whatever you are trying to insert is not passing one of the CHECK constraints.

Whenever you get an Informix error number, use it as a parameter for the Finderr tool. (e.g. finderr 530). It will give you more information about that particular error. If you try it with '530' you will see there is even a SQL statement to identify which particular constraint using the name in the error message.

Comment: @J_S Yes, Im getting the error in the insert script. I need to know how to name each constraint so when something fails, I can easily identify it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SQL standard positions constraint names before the constraint 'body', whereas [Informix](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.sqls.doc/ids_sqs_0509.htm) positions the constraint names after the constraint body.

Thus, in standard SQL, you might write:

```
…
grado INT  CONSTRAINT usuarios_grado CHECK (grado > 0 AND grado < 8),
…
```

but in Informix's dialect, you need to write:

```
…
grado INT  CHECK (grado > 0 AND grado < 8) CONSTRAINT usuarios_grado,
…
```

Comment: As a complete aside, I wonder why and how the frick such things can possibly ever happen.  Did the Informix labs beat the standard wrt to constraint naming feature ?  And even if so, considering IBM's supposedly strong lobby position in the standards committee, how did the standard get to be different ?

Comment: My best guess is that Informix implemented what was proposed in a draft standard (but not the FDIS or final draft international standard), not expecting it to change, and released the product, but the standards committee changed its mind, leaving Informix stuck.  This would have been in the early 90s, just prior to SQL-92, I think.  Some of the INTERVAL notation used by Informix suffers likewise, and the DATETIME stuff is different from the standard too.  Of course, it's hard to be sure this much later, and I wasn't privy to the server development at the time.

Answer (score 2):

To expand on Erwin's answer:

```
CREATE TABLE Usuarios
 (
  CI  INT PRIMARY KEY,
  primer_nombre   varchar(25) NOT NULL CHECK (primer_nombre MATCHES '^[a-zA-Z]$' ) CONSTRAINT constraint_primer_nombre 
 ); 
> insert into Usuarios values (1,'asd');

  530: Check constraint (Administrator.constraint_primer_nombre) failed.
Error in line 1
Near character position 36
>
```

Answer (score 1):

In general SQL is devised so that all supported constraints can be assigned a name.  For the particular SQL dialect of the engine you're using, refer to your engine's [SQL Syntax](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.sqls.doc/ids_sqs_0509.htm) manual.